# Unable to click in a dropdown menu with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to click on a link inside a dropdown menu, but I keep getting a TimeoutException, using XPATH.

```
test = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li[4]/ul/li[7]/a")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", test)
```

But if I try to click on the Log Out option the script *sometimes* works.

```
logOut = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li[7]/ul/li/a")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", logOut)
```

There are 3 dropdown menus. The test is in a menu with some 12 options and the Log Out is in another by itself. I want to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code for the menus.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row headerLogo">
            <!--<header class="navbar-default navbar-static-top headerLogo">-->
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="vericaltext">WIISCPRD23V</div>
                <a href="/Home" id="linkHome"><img src="/Content/images/Logo_menu2.png" class="logoSea" alt='SEA'  /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="row flat-nav">
                    <li class="color20 effect3">
                        <a><i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-2x"></i><span>Peq</span></a>

                        <ul class="column-based">
                                <li class="color20" style="font-weight:bold">Question</li>
                                            <li><a href="/Quest">Quest</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/Retr">Retr</a></li>
                                <li class="color20" style="font-weight:bold">Vitss</li>
                                            <li><a href="/Vit">Vit</a></li>
                                <li class="color20" style="font-weight:bold">BC</li>
                                            <li><a href="/Trat">Trat</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/BC">BC</a></li>
                                <li class="color20" style="font-weight:bold">CAD</li>
                                            <li><a href="/Cad">Ant</a></li>
                                <li class="color20" style="font-weight:bold">Fer</li>
                                            <li><a href="/Add">Add</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/Emp">Emp</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/Est">Est</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/Seg">Seg</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/Rec">Rec</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/Cal">Cal</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="color49 effect3">
                        <a><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i><span>E-mails</span></a>

            <li class="color5 effect3 divLogout">

                <a>
                    <div style="width:100%;padding-top:15px">
                        <div class="divAlinhadaEsquerda"><i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-3x"></i></div>
                        <div class="divAlinhadaEsquerda">
                            <div class="fontNomUsr">xxx</div> 
                            <div class="fontUser">xxx&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </div>
                                <div class="fontUlti">xxx</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <ul class="column-based">
                    <li><a href="/Home/Logout"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i><span>Sair</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show us the DOM? Is it created dynamically?

Comment: Are you trying to click on a Add link ?

Comment: The one I'm trying to click on is ' <li><a href="/Trat">Trat</a></li>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath is incorrect, please try below solution :
Solution 1:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PesquisasElement=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Pesquisas')]")))

TratamentoElement=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/ManterBC']")))


#Create the object for Action Chains
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(PesquisasElement).move_to_element(TratamentoElement).click()
actions.perform()
```

Comment: I'm still getting TimeoutException, unfortunately. Also, is there a typo in `li[@claass='color20 effect3']`? I edited to @class.

Comment: @Luck: There was a typo in the xpath, which I just corrected.

Comment: I tried both ways, but neither seems to be working. I keep getting TimeoutException.

Comment: Sorry, that wouldn't be possible. But I posted the code as it is, changing only minor stuff that's not important in this case like classes name.

Comment: @DipakBachhav I tried, but it still doesn't work. I've tried to click other links on the page and they all work.

Comment: I don't know if this is worth mentioning or not, but the options only appear after you hover the mouse over the top menu.

Comment: Can you please provide all information ?  Like options are appeared after  hovering on which element

Comment: @DipakBachhav I've tried the '/Home' one in this part. `<div class="row headerLogo">
            <!--<header class="navbar-default navbar-static-top headerLogo">-->
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="vericaltext">WIISCPRD23V</div>
                <a href="/Home" id="linkHome"><img src="/Content/images/Logo_Sipea_menu2.png" class="logoSistema" alt='SEA'  /></a>
            </div>
`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not being very clear. I'm new to all this and it's hard even to ask the questions properly. I need to hover on this part `<a><i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-2x"></i><span>Peq</span></a>`

Comment: Yeah. You can find me at luckntd@gmail.com